# Xamarin Forms Background Transfer Service for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-background

I’ve written an App that uses NSURLSessionUploadTask to upload data to a web service.  This is first written to the file system and then handed off to iOS so that the upload will happen in the background.

I need to do something similar with Android, however I’m not sure what the best solution is.  I’ve come across android-upload-service on github (https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service), however I can’t find an example for Xamarin Forms -has anyone used this?  I’ve also seen FileUploaderPlugin on github (https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin), however this doesn’t seem to support background processing?

Comment: I was able to implement Android background upload, largely using this as a reference: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16721/getting-a-syncadapter-to-work. In the end, the hard part for me was wrapping my head around Android's background processing model; the code isn't really that bad, with way more boilerplate than I would have expected.